# Yii request Model from component controller

Tags: php, yii

I have a public function that is duplicated over multiple controllers, so I wanted to simplify this, so moved my function into the base controller (component/controller) as all controllers extend this.

This works fine, however, within my function, a case statement checks several items within an Options Model.

```
$url = Options::getSlackWebhookUrl();
```

Functions are set up to get data within the model and all works fine, but when inside the component/controller, i get the following error;

```
Error 500
include(Options.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to to access a model within the component/controller?

Comment: are you using yii1 or yii2?

Comment: I'm using yii1 @scaisEdge

Comment: seems a path problem ...

Comment: Path is the same as accessing in controllers (like siteController, pagesController for example) - don't know how you would make a different path to models

Comment: don't find Option.php the try adding the relative  path

Comment: check in main.php weather models are imported or not

Comment: You need to include it via main.php or using Yii::import()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the function locally in component/controller, you could just use

```
$this->getSlackWebhookUrl();
```

or, if you want to reference the function statically

```
self::getSlackWebhookUrl();
```